# library time.h with the C++

Tags: c++

i want to display message "Hello world !" for 2 minutes.
This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int gameTime;
    clock_t temps;

    cout << "Insert the time (minute) :  ";
    cin >> gameTime;
    gameTime = gameTime * 60;

    do {
        cout << "Hello world !" << endl;
    }while ( ((temps = clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) == gameTime );

    return 0;
}
```

it doesn't work ! Help please

Comment: You need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: `clock()` does not start at 0. `clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is almost 100% certainly larger than 120 when you start your program.

Comment: May I suggest instead of `clock`  you use a `std::chrono::steady_clock`?

Comment: always the same as the other functions I had to use.
I want to do a number of things in a given time. I can not do that!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
while ( ((temps = clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) == gameTime );
```

tells the computer to repeat **while** `((temps = clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) == gameTime` resolves to `true`.

`((temps = clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) == gameTime` resolves to `true` when `((temps = clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)` is **equal** to `gameTime`.

This happens only **once**, specifically when `clock()` returns a value that is equal to `gameTime*CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Since you want your code to repeat, but your condition to keep it repeating is only true in one specific situation, your code will probably never loop, or only loop for as long as `clock()` returns the right value, if it by pure chance returns the right value in the beginning.

You need to rethink what you're trying to do. **Hint**: You want it to repeat **while** `gameTime` is **greater** than the current time. And you also want `gameTime` to be an offset from the current time at the beginning of your code.